# Wordpress admin settings page - extracting array

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking at building a plugin with a admin settings page. Looking at the codex, I have the following code:

```
<?php

class MyNewPlugin
{
/**
 * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
 */
private $options;

/**
 * Start up
 */
public function __construct()
{
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
}

/**
 * Add options page
 */
public function add_plugin_page()
{
    // This page will be under "Settings"
    add_options_page(
        'Settings Admin', 
        'My New Plugin', 
        'manage_options', 
        'my-new-plugin-admin', 
        array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
    );
}

/**
 * Options page callback
 */
public function create_admin_page()
{
    // Set class property
    $this->options = get_option( 'my_new_plugin_option' );
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon(); ?>
        <h2>My New Plugin Settings</h2>           
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php
            // This prints out all hidden setting fields
            settings_fields( 'my_new_plugin_option_group' );   
            do_settings_sections( 'my-new-plugin-admin' );
            submit_button(); 
        ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Register and add settings
 */
public function page_init()
{        
    register_setting(
        'my_new_plugin_option_group', // Option group
        'my_new_plugin_option', // Option name
        array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
    );

    add_settings_section(
        'setting_section_id', // ID
        'Settings', // Title
        array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
        'my-new-plugin-admin' // Page
    );         

    add_settings_field(
        'title', 
        'Title', 
        array( $this, 'title_callback' ), 
        'my-new-plugin-admin', 
        'setting_section_id'
    );  

    add_settings_field(
        'addresslineone', 
        'Address Line One', 
        array( $this, 'addresslineone_callback' ), 
        'my-new-plugin-admin', 
        'setting_section_id'
    ); 

    add_settings_field(
        'addresslinetwo', 
        'Address Line Two', 
        array( $this, 'addresslinetwo_callback' ), 
        'my-new-plugin-admin', 
        'setting_section_id'
    ); 
}

/**
 * Sanitize each setting field as needed
 *
 * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
 */
public function sanitize( $input )
{
    if( isset( $input['title'] ) )
        $new_input['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['title'] );

    if( isset( $input['addresslineone'] ) )
        $new_input['addresslineone'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['addresslineone'] ); 

    if( isset( $input['addresslinetwo'] ) )
        $new_input['addresslinetwo'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['addresslinetwo'] );     

    return $new_input;
}

/** 
 * Print the Section text
 */
public function print_section_info()
{
    print 'Enter your settings below:';
}

/** 
 * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
 */
public function title_callback()
{
    printf(
        '<input type="text" id="title" name="my_new_plugin_option[title]" value="%s" />',
        isset( $this->options['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['title']) : ''
    );
}

/** 
 * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
 */
public function addresslineone_callback()
{
    printf(
        '<input type="text" id="addresslineone" name="my_new_plugin_option[addresslineone]" value="%s" />',
        isset( $this->options['addresslineone'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['addresslineone']) : ''
    );
}

public function addresslinetwo_callback()
{
    printf(
        '<input type="text" id="addresslinetwo" name="my_new_plugin_option[addresslinetwo]" value="%s" />',
        isset( $this->options['addresslinetwo'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['addresslinetwo']) : ''
    );
}
}

if( is_admin() )
    $my_new_plugin_settings = new MyNewPlugin();

include_once "mynewpluginwidget.php";
```

A simple plugin to start off with, the user enters the settings on the setting page and it displays in the widget area (user has to add the widget where they want it to be).

The question is, how do I extract the settings and display them? I presume they are in the array $this, but cannot get them to display..

Comment: Have you read [Settings API with arrays example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100137/73)?

Comment: No :) will do now, thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. Ok, read through that, but still not sure how to extract the data from the array? Would I use the get_option() function on the front end?

Comment: I would use a separate class to handle to data access (you might want to change the storage to a separate table later without changing the other code). Then use that class to get the data on front end.

Comment: Ok, so the plugin will call a new class that creates the widget. Would I then use "$title = get_option( 'my_new_plugin_option', 'title' );" and then "echo $title;" to display in the widget?

Comment: Actually, used: "echo $title = get_option( 'my_new_plugin_option', 'title' );" and it just displays "Array".